# Feed my own image data on caffe

Tags: matlab, hdf5, caffe

I trying create a HDF5 file for use in caffe, I using Matlab with standard codes "demo.m" and "store2hdf5.m", the .h5 file is created without problems, but when I go to start the training I got this error:

> I0423 09:56:45.906390 11678 net.cpp:454] deconv <- data_data_0_split_1
>   I0423 09:56:45.906400 11678 net.cpp:411] deconv -> deconv F0423
>   09:56:45.907380 11678 filler.hpp:249] Check failed: blob->num_axes()
>   == 4 (1 vs. 4) Blob must be 4 dim.
>   *** Check failure stack trace: ***

My 4D matrix is storage on this form:

> HDF5 test.h5 Group '/'
>       Dataset 'data'
>           Size:  32x32x3x1024
>           MaxSize:  32x32x3xInf
>           Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
>           ChunkSize:  32x32x3x256
>           Filters:  none
>           FillValue:  0.000000
>       Dataset 'label'
>           Size:  32x32x3x1024
>           MaxSize:  32x32x3xInf
>           Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
>           ChunkSize:  32x32x3x256
>           Filters:  none
>           FillValue:  0.000000

Someone have any idea of which i can do?

Thanks

Comment: please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410): you probably need to use `permute` when saving hdf5 data from MATLAB.

Comment: thanks Shai, this works.