# Error : H5LTfind_dataset(file_id, dataset_name_) Failed to find HDF5 dataset label

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, hdf5, caffe, conv-neural-network

I want to use HDF5 file to input my data and labels in my CNN.
I created the hdf5 file with matlab.

Here is my code:

```
h5create(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/train/image',[522 775 3 numFrames]);
h5create(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/train/anno',[522 775 3 numFrames]);
h5create(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/label',[1 numFrames]);`


h5write(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/train/image',images);
h5write(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/train/anno',anno);
h5write(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/label',label);`
```

Where `image`, `anno` are 4D `unit8` and `label` is a 1x85 `unit16` vector.

When I display my .h5 file I got this:

> ```
> HDF5 uNetDataSet.h5
> Group '/'
>   Group '/home'
>     Group '/home/alexandra'
>         Group '/home/alexandra/Documents'
>             Group '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net'
>                 Group '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset'
>                     Group '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset'
>                         Dataset 'label'
>                             Size:  1x85
>                             MaxSize:  1x85
>                             Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
>                             ChunkSize:  []
>                             Filters:  none
>                             FillValue:  0.000000
>                         Group '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/train'
>                             Dataset 'anno'
>                                 Size:  522x775x3x85
>                                 MaxSize:  522x775x3x85
>                                 Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
>                                 ChunkSize:  []
>                                 Filters:  none
>                                 FillValue:  0.000000
>                             Dataset 'image'
>                                 Size:  522x775x3x85
>                                 MaxSize:  522x775x3x85
>                                 Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
>                                 ChunkSize:  []
>                                 Filters:  none
>                                 FillValue:  0.000000`
> ```

When I read the label dataset with `h5read` it works.

But when I try to train my network I got this error:

> ```
> I0713 09:47:18.620510  4278 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loadMydata
> I0713 09:47:18.620535  4278 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer loadMydata
> I0713 09:47:18.620550  4278 net.cpp:399] loadMydata -> label
> I0713 09:47:18.620580  4278 net.cpp:399] loadMydata -> anno
> I0713 09:47:18.620600  4278 net.cpp:399] loadMydata -> image
> I0713 09:47:18.620622  4278 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5     filenames from: /home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/my_data.txt
> I0713 09:47:18.620656  4278 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 1
> F0713 09:47:18.621317  4278 hdf5.cpp:14] Check failed:     H5LTfind_dataset(file_id, dataset_name_) Failed to find HDF5 dataset label
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>     @     0x7f2edf557daa  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f2edf557ce4  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f2edf5576e6  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f2edf55a687  (unknown)
>     @     0x7f2edf908597  caffe::hdf5_load_nd_dataset_helper<>()
>     @     0x7f2edf907365  caffe::hdf5_load_nd_dataset<>()
>     @     0x7f2edf9579fe  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LoadHDF5FileData()
>     @     0x7f2edf956818  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
>     @     0x7f2edf94fcbc  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>     @     0x7f2edf950b45  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>     @     0x7f2edf91d08a  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
>     @     0x7f2edf91e18c  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>     @     0x7f2edf91e4ba  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>     @     0x7f2edf930ed3  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
>     @           0x40e67e  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
>     @           0x40794b  train()
>     @           0x40590c  main
>     @     0x7f2ede865f45  (unknown)
>     @           0x406041  (unknown)
>     @              (nil)  (unknown)
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

In my .prototxt file :

```
layer {
  top: 'label'
  top:'anno'
  top: 'image'
  name: 'loadMydata'
  type: "HDF5Data"
  hdf5_data_param { source: '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/my_data.txt' batch_size: 1 } 
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}
```

I don't know where I did something wrong, if anyone could help me it would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your hdf5 file `'uNetDataSet.h5'` does not have `label` in it.
What you have instead is `'/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/warwick_dataset/Warwick_Dataset/label'` - I hope you can spot the difference.

Try creating the dataset with

```
h5create(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/image',[522 775 3 numFrames]);
h5create(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/anno',[522 775 3 numFrames]);
h5create(['uNetDataSet.h5'],'/label',[1 numFrames]);
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410) for more details. Also note that you might need to `permute` the input data before saving it to hdf5 using matlab.