# caffe hdf5 H5LTfind_dataset(file_id, dataset_name_) Failed to find HDF5 dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I was using HDF5 as one of the input to feed caffe, the hdf5 file only contains some weight information to put in the sigmoidcrossentropyloss layer so it doesn't contain any `label`.This error occured:

> ```
>     I1015 07:08:54.605777 17909 net.cpp:100] Creating Layer weight28
>     I1015 07:08:54.605797 17909 net.cpp:408] weight28 -> weight28
>     I1015 07:08:54.605834 17909 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: /home/zhangyu/codes/unsupervised/data/weight28.txt
>     I1015 07:08:54.605926 17909 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 1
>     F1015 07:08:54.608682 17909 hdf5.cpp:14] Check failed: H5LTfind_dataset(file_id, dataset_name_) Failed to find HDF5 dataset weight28
>     *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>         @     0x7f17077ec9fd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
>         @     0x7f17077ee89d  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
>         @     0x7f17077ec5ec  google::LogMessage::Flush()
>         @     0x7f17077ef1be  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
>         @     0x7f1707e4d774  caffe::hdf5_load_nd_dataset_helper<>()
>         @     0x7f1707e4bcf0  caffe::hdf5_load_nd_dataset<>()
>         @     0x7f1707e8fd78  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LoadHDF5FileData()
>         @     0x7f1707e8ebf8  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
>         @     0x7f1707e283b2  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>         @     0x7f1707e2ad85  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>         @     0x7f1707e6da5f  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
>         @     0x7f1707e6df7b  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>         @     0x7f1707e6e3e8  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>         @     0x7f1707e865a3  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
>         @           0x4116b1  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
>         @           0x40ac56  train()
>         @           0x406e32  main
>         @     0x7f17066adf45  (unknown)
>         @           0x4074b6  (unknown)
> ```

I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348238/error-h5ltfind-datasetfile-id-dataset-name-failed-to-find-hdf5-dataset-lab) for this problem and it seems that my hdf5 file need a dataset **label**, but the fact is I don't need that. I only need a dataset of `91250x28x28`. And feed it to the loss layer as weights. Here is my h5 file:

```
HDF5 weight28.h5 
Group '/' 
    Dataset 'data' 
        Size:  2555000x28
        MaxSize:  Infx28
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
        ChunkSize:  28x28
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000
```

I modified the sigmiodcrossentropy layer to add it as a third bottom layer:

```
// modified here
  const Dtype* pixelweights = bottom[2]->cpu->data();

  Dtype loss = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    loss -= pixelweights(i)*(input_data[i] * (target[i] - (input_data[i] >= 0)) -
            log(1 + exp(input_data[i] - 2 * input_data[i] * (input_data[i] >= 0))));
  }
  top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = loss / num;
}
```

The proto file:

```
layer {
  name: "loss_G"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "global_smR"
  bottom: "mask28"
  bottom: "weight28"  //Added it here
  top: "loss_G"
}
```

I was expected that a batch of the data in the h5 file will be read to the net as `bottom[2]`(size batchsize*28*28). 
Here is the question.

- Can I get what I expected from the code above?
- Do I have to add a label set in the h5 file to solve the error?
- If I add it to the h5 file, how should I handle the extra label data in the loss layer?

Any advice will be appraciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `"HDF5Data"` has `top` named `"weight28"`, but your `h5` file has only dataset `"data"`. The `"top"` of `"HDF5Data"` layer **must** be the same as the Dataset name stored in the `h5` file. If you have more than one dataset dtored in the same file, you can have multiple `top`s with the names of the Datasets in the `h5` file.