# How to load multiple files to caffe model

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I am trying to use the following caffe model for prediction "https://github.com/amandajshao/www_deep_crowd". this model don't take as input an image but it takes some motion and appearance features. I have those features for every frame as .mat files and converted them to hdf5.
but i couldn't figure out how to load them to caffe.
any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Converting to HDF5 is more than half the way there...

[`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer can produce several `"top"`s: one for each dataset stored in the hdf5 file. So, suppose you [used matlab to write your hdf5 files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261942/1714410)

```
hdf5write('my_data.h5', 'motion', single( motion )  );
hdf5write('my_data.h5', 'appearance', single(appearnace), 'WriteMode', 'append' );
```

Then you can have an `"HDF5Data"` layer with two `"top`"s:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "motion"
  top: "appearance"
  hdf5_data_param { source: "path/to/hdf_list.txt" }
}
```

You might want to pay close attention to the order the data is stored, as Matlab stores arrays in "Fortran" fashion, while caffe expects its data ordered in a "C" fashion. See [this post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410).

Comment: thank you for reply. Actually, I am not trying to train a model. I need to use  a pretrained caffe model to predict my own data. The authors of this pretrained model haven't provided the train_val.prototxt they provided only the deploy_prototxt. My issue is that the hdf5 files should be given as input for the prediction not the training.