# Caffe: Check failed: shape[i] >= 0 (-1 vs. 0) error

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I am trying to design a network that takes an IMAGE (224x224x3) and 3 parameters (X,Y,R) learns the relation.

My input is an HDF5 dataset. I am getting the following error:

"Creating Layer conv1
I0612 17:17:38.315083  9991 net.cpp:406] conv1 <- data
I0612 17:17:38.315107  9991 net.cpp:380] conv1 -> conv1
F0612 17:17:38.352540  9991 blob.cpp:32] Check failed: shape[i] >= 0 (-1 vs. 0) "

I have created an HDF5 dataset for input to caffe. My create_dataset code is as follows:-

```
import h5py, os
import caffe
import numpy as np

SIZE = 224
with open( 'val.txt', 'r' ) as T :
    lines = T.readlines()


count_files = 0
split_after = 199
count = -1

# If you do not have enough memory split data into
# multiple batches and generate multiple separate h5 files
data = np.zeros( (split_after,SIZE, SIZE,3), dtype='f4' )
label = np.zeros( (split_after,3, 1), dtype='f4' )

for i,l in enumerate(lines):
    count += 1
    sp = l.split(' ')
    img = caffe.io.load_image( sp[0] )
    data[count] = img
    label[count][0] = float(sp[1])
    label[count][1] = float(sp[2])
    label[count][2] = float(sp[3])
    #print y1[count]
    if (count+1) == split_after:
    with h5py.File('val_' + str(count_files) +  '.h5','w') as H:
        H.create_dataset( 'data', data=data ) # note the name X given to the dataset!
        H.create_dataset( 'label', data=label )
        data = np.zeros( (split_after, SIZE, SIZE, 3), dtype='f4' )
        label = np.zeros( (split_after,3, 1), dtype='f4' )
    with open('val1.txt','a') as L:
        L.write( 'val_' + str(count_files) + '.h5') # list all h5 files you are going to use
    count_files += 1
    count = 0
```

I am creating a data (224,224,3) field and a label (3,1) in the HDF5 dataset.

Now my caffe model is as follows:

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/home/arijit/Downloads/caffe/Circle/test1.txt"
    batch_size: 256
    shuffle: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/home/arijit/Downloads/caffe/Circle/val1.txt"
    batch_size: 16
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc8ft"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8ft"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "fc8ft"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

The detailed error is as follows:-

"Creating Layer conv1
I0612 17:17:38.315083  9991 net.cpp:406] conv1 <- data
I0612 17:17:38.315107  9991 net.cpp:380] conv1 -> conv1
F0612 17:17:38.352540  9991 blob.cpp:32] Check failed: shape[i] >= 0 (-1 vs. 0) "

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the shape of your input image backwards:. 
Instead of `H`x`W`x`3`, caffe expects it to be `3`x`W`x`H`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410) for some more details about arranging arrays for caffe in hdf5 files.

PS,
You do not need the Singleton dimension in your `label` array.

Comment: When I try to change the line no 17 to
data = np.zeros((split_after, 3, SIZE, SIZE), dtype='f4')
I get an error 
Could not broadcast input array from shape (227,227,3) into shape (3,227,227)

Comment: you need to transpose your input

Comment: It does work now! But after running it,during the validation always produces the same output for all the test images.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message. But it seems my case is different from the questioner.

I met with this error because I added too many convolutional and pooling layers in my network, and the images finally shrunk to 1x1, in which case if I continued to add convolutional layers, the convolution cannot be performed, and this error appeared.

In case some one else meets with my problem, I post it here.

Comment: Kinda embarassed I ran into this...Thanks!