# How to create HDF5 database of 3D data for pycaffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, hdf5, pycaffe, matcaffe

My question may sound easy, however, I have difficulty in creating an Hdf5 dataset from my 3d medical images that have been saved in `nii` format for both images and manual segmentation (label files). My questions are:

1. The blob shape in `pycaffe` is `N*C*W*H`, is it different order in matcaffe? for example in pycaffe the data blob shape will be `1*1*60*320*320` for a grayscale volume with width and height 320-by-320 and 60 slices. I tried to use a `Matlab` [code](https://github.com/yulequan/HeartSeg/blob/master/code/prepare_h5_data.m) to create HDF5 dataset for the 3D data, and the order of blob in `hdf5info` file is `320*320*60*1*1` for both `data` and `label`. How should I change the orders in the Matlab code to be readable in Pycaffe?
2. Is there any python code for creating the hdf5 database for 3D data?
3. if I create the hdf5 data in Matlab and use the list the pycaffe, will it raise issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Matlab arranges elements in ND arrays from the first dimension to the last (like [fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)), while caffe and hdf5 stores the arrays from last dimension to first ("col-major").
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410) explains how to simply modify Matlab's code to write "col-major" arrays to HDF5 files.
You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261942/1714410) useful for your problem.

Comment: Thank you, is the blob shape in pycaffe for 3D data  is like N,C,H,W,D, in which D stands for depth?

Comment: @user630317 it depends how you design the net.

Comment: @user630317 I suppose it is usually NxCxDxHxW (you first store each slice and then move to the next one).

Comment: could I ask for each group of image and label should we have separate `.h5` files? for example, if I have `im-01.nii`, `im-02.nii`, ..., and their corresponding label volumes, `lb-01.nii`, `lb-02.nii`, ..., the hdf5 list includes, `im-01.h5`, `im-02.h5`, etc.

Comment: There is a conflict here if I am not mistaken, In [VNet](https://github.com/faustomilletari/VNet/blob/master/Prototxt/test_noPooling_ResNet_cinque.prototxt#L2) the order of input shape is `input_shape{dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 128 dim: 128 dim: 64}`, that means `depth:64` comes to end.

Comment: @user630317 if this is the way your net is defined - then go with it.